# Swift 3 Calendar.range - migrate function

Tags: swift, swift3

I am not sure how to migrate this function correctly to swift 3.

```
extension Date {  

    func numberOfDaysUntilDateTime(toDateTime: NSDate, calendar:NSCalendar) -> Int {  

        var fromDate: NSDate?, toDate: NSDate?  

        calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &fromDate, interval: nil, forDate: self)  
        calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &toDate, interval: nil, forDate: toDateTime)  

        let difference = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: fromDate!, toDate: toDate!, options: [])  

        return difference.day  

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See for example this answer [How to get the 'n' weekday of a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527084/how-to-get-the-n-weekday-of-a-date/39527482#39527482) on how to use `rangeOfUnit` in Swift 3.

However, there is an easier method to get the start of the day
for a date which translates directly to Swift 3:

```
extension Date {
    func numberOfDaysUntilDateTime(toDateTime: Date, calendar: Calendar) -> Int {
        let fromDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: self)
        let toDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: toDateTime)
        let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: fromDate, to: toDate)
        return difference.day!
    }
}
```