# How to get the 'n' weekday of a Date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift3, nscalendar

I need to translate this function into swift.
Basically what does it get the 'n' day of the current week. So for example if i use it with NSDate().getWeekDay(0) it gives me Sun 11 Sept, and so on.
But seems rangeOfUnit no longer exists in Swift-3.
This was my previous implementation in Swift-2

```
extension NSDate {
    func getWeekDay(day: Int) -> NSDate {
        var beginningOfWeek: NSDate?
        NSCalendar.currentCalendar().rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, startDate: &beginningOfWeek, interval: nil, forDate: self)
        let comps = NSDateComponents()
        comps.day = day
        comps.minute = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: self)
        comps.hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: self)
        let nextDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(comps, toDate: beginningOfWeek!, options: .SearchBackwards)
        return nextDate!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative to get the start of the week which
translates directly to Swift  3:

```
extension Date {
    func getWeekDay(day: Int) -> Date {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        let comps = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: self)
        let beginningOfWeek = cal.date(from: comps)!
        let nextDate = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: beginningOfWeek)!
        return nextDate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your extension in Swift 3 for `Date` and a bit optimized

```
extension Date {
  func getWeekDay(day: Int) -> Date {
    var beginningOfWeek = Date()
    var interval : TimeInterval = 0
    let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
    currentCalendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &beginningOfWeek, interval: &interval, for: self)
    return currentCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: beginningOfWeek)!
  }
}
```

`rangeOfUnit(startDate:interval:forDate:)` has been turned into `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:)` in the new `Calendar` structure.