# NSDate from Swift 2.3 to Date from Swift 3 Conversion

Tags: date, nsdate, swift3, xcode8

So I've just updated to Xcode 8 and converted my Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3, and Swift 3 just converted all `NSDate` to `Foundation.Date`

And I had an `extension` for `NSDate`, now called`Foundation.Date`, it looked like this:

```
extension NSDate
{
  var firstDayOfTheMonth:NSDate
  {
     var date: NSDate?
     NSCalendar.currentCalendar().rangeOfUnit(.Month, startDate:&date , interval: nil, forDate: self)
     return date!
  }
}
```

And Swift 3 converted it to this:

```
extension Foundation.Date
{
  var firstDayOfTheMonth:Foundation.Date
  {
     var date: Foundation.Date?
    (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).range(of: .month, start:&date , interval: nil, for: self)
     return date!
  }
}
```

The problem here is that Xcode suggests me to do this : `Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'NSDate?'` and to drop the `&`.

So, I change it and the function now looks like this:

```
extension Foundation.Date
{
  var firstDayOfTheMonth:Foundation.Date
  {
     var date: Foundation.Date?
    (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).range(of: .month, start:date as NSDate?, interval: nil, for: self)
     return date!
  }
}
```

But now Xcode says `Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to type 'NSDate?' in coercion`

How can I make this work?

Comment: `rangeOfUnit` is `dateInterval` in Swift 3, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/39527482/1187415.

Comment: You're right Martin R, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this conversion is not the best work of the migrator ;-)

This is the Swift 3 equivalent of your code

```
extension Date
{
  var firstDayOfTheMonth:Date
  {
    var date = Date()
    var interval : TimeInterval = 0
    Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .month, start: &date, interval: &interval, for: self)
    return date
  }
}
```

The `interval` parameter seems to be mandatory even if it's not used.