# Get Week Swift 3

Tags: date, swift3

How can I convert this to be supported in Swift 3? Right now I am getting an error that says:

Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer?'

But the error just keeps changing to something else, so I'm in a circle

```
    func getNumPOCThisWeek() {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    var startOfWeek : Date?
    (calendar as NSCalendar).range(of: .weekOfYear, start: startOfWeek, interval: nil, for: Date())

    //        let weekObj : WeekList!
    let query = WeekList.query()!
    query.whereKey("weekStart", equalTo: startOfWeek!)
    do {
        let weekObj = try query.getFirstObject() as! WeekList
        print(weekObj)

        let weekNumber = ScheduleObject.query()!
        weekNumber.whereKey("weekObj", equalTo: weekObj)
        weekNumber.countObjectsInBackground(block: { (counted : Int32, error : Error?) in
            self.thisWeekPOCNumber.text = String(counted)
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
         }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39581357/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better specify what line is causing the error.

Assuming this line:

```
(calendar as NSCalendar).range(of: .weekOfYear, start: startOfWeek, interval: nil, for: Date())
```

Check the [latest reference of `NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar):

> ```
> func range(of: NSCalendar.Unit, start: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDate?>?, interval: UnsafeMutablePointer<TimeInterval>?, for: Date)
> ```

The type of `start` parameter is `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDate?>?`, so you need to declare a variable of `NSDate?`:

```
var startOfWeek : NSDate?
(calendar as NSCalendar).range(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfWeek, interval: nil, for: Date())
```

This change may force you to fix some other parts, but I cannot say anything as your code if full of mysteries like `WeekList` or `ScheduleObject`...

---

Or else, you can use the Swift `Calendar` rather than `NSCalendar`:

```
var startOfWeek : Date = Date()
var interval: TimeInterval = TimeInterval()
calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfWeek, interval: &interval, for: Date())
```